# C++ Error: undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c++

I'm working on a simple class List, but when compiling the header and cpp file, I get the error: undefined reference to `main'

What am I doing wrong, and how could I fix this?

Here is the list.h file that has simple headers:

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <string>

const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

class List
{
    public:
        List();
        List(int capacity);
        ~List();
        void push_back(std::string s);
        int size() const;
        std::string at(int index) const;

    private:
        std::string* mData;
        int mSize;
        int mCapacity;
};

#endif
```

And here is the list.cpp file:

**list.cpp**

```
#include "list.h"
#include <string>

List::List(){
    mData = new std::string[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    mSize = 0;
    mCapacity = 100;
};

List::List(int capacity){
    mData = new std::string[capacity];
    mSize = 0;
    mCapacity = capacity;
};

List::~List(){
    delete[] mData;
};

void List::push_back(std::string s){
    if (mSize<mCapacity){
        mData[mSize] = s;
        mSize++;
    }
};

int List::size() const{
    return mSize;
};

std::string List::at(int index) const{
    return mData[index];
};
```

I tried experimenting around with "using namespace std" and how to include , but I can't figure out how to get these errors to go away. What is causing them?

Comment: Where's the main function?

Comment: You need an `int main()` function.

Comment: Unless your program is not an executable, the `main` function is mandatory. You have to create the `main` function to build the application.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally forgot and knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Undefined reference to main() means that your program lacks a main() function, which is mandatory for all C++ programs. Add this somewhere:

```
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

You should be able to *compile* `list.cpp`, you can't *link* it unless you have a main program. (That might be a slight oversimplification.)

The way to compile a source file without linking it depends on what compiler you're using. If you're using `g++`, the command would be:

```
g++ -c list.cpp
```

That will generate an object file containing the machine code for your class. Depending on your compiler and OS, it might be called `list.o` or `list.obj`.

If you instead try:

```
g++ list.cpp
```

it will assume that you've defined a `main` function and try to generate an executable, resulting in the error you've seen (because you *haven't* defined a `main` function).

At some point, of course, you'll need a program that uses your class.  To do that, you'll need another `.cpp` source file that has a `#include "list.h"` and a `main()` function. You can compile that source file and link the resulting object together with the object generated from `list.cpp` to generate a working executable.  With `g++`, you can do that in one step, for example:

```
g++ list.cpp main.cpp -o main
```

You have to have a `main` function somewhere. It doesn't necessarily have to be in `list.cpp`. And as a matter of style and code organization, it probably shouldn't be in `list.cpp`; you might want to be able to use that class from more than one main program.